# How to run modified pipeline in R?

Tags: r

I've got R package, and I went inside of it and toke the source code(.R), I put it in separate folder. I changed  some parts inside of it. my modification was correct, but when I want to run the modified .R pipline, nothing happen. I mean it's do nothing(pipeline doesn't work) and I don't get any error.
Can anybody tell me how can I run it ?

I do line this :

```
>source(pileline.R)
>
```

first few lines of pipeline are like this:

```
run.pipeline = function( indata=mydata1, dataset.name = "Unnamed", dim.som1 = 20, dim.som2 = 20 )
{

    preferences = list()
    preferences$dataset.name = dataset.name
    preferences$dim.som1 = dim.som1
    preferences$dim.som2 = dim.som2

    preferences$sample.spot.cutoff = 0.65
    preferences$summary.spot.cutoff = 0.95
```

Comment: `source(pipeline.R)` will add `run.pipeline` to your environment, as-if you had copy-pasted the code from the file into your R session. Type `print(run.pipeline)` and you should see it is the case. `source` won't *run* the function for you (with what arguments anyway?).

Comment: @flodel, I'm trying this, but it's print my whole script on the terminal. it doesn't run my script. what should I do ?

Comment: You don't seem to understand well the concept of a function. You are confusing definition (`foo <- function(...) {...}`) and usage (`result <- foo(...)`). I'd recommend you pick up an introduction to programming. The immediate answer to your problem though, is to run `run.pipeline()`. Also, most likely you did not have to hack the package, just call its function with your own arguments.

Answer (score 1):

try source(pipeline.R, print.eval = TRUE)

Comment: this will only work in the present session if pipeline.R is in the working directory. OP might want to look at using `setwd()` as well.